How to protect myself against sandwiches (MEV)?
At the last days I'm getting sandwiched like more than 4 times a day while I must use high slippage, and jito isn't good enough solution because it delays my buys at most.
How I can protect myself against them ? I heard it's possible through making program on chain but there should be code inside the program that is blocking the MEVs as far as I understand that.
I'll be glad for any help, thanks !
